# Django FormView: form_valid() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have the following views to display a page where you see a detail view of a book and post a comment/review below:

```
class BookDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Book

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = BookReviewForm()
        return context

class BookComment(SingleObjectMixin, FormView):
    template_name = 'book/book_detail.html'
    form_class = BookReviewForm
    model = Book

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return HttpResponseForbidden()
        self.object = self.get_object()
        return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('book_detail', args=[str(self.object.id)])

class BookDetail(View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        view = BookDetailView.as_view()
        return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        view = BookComment.as_view()
        return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

The review class:

```
class Review(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(
        Book,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='reviews',
    )
    review = models.CharField(max_length=5000)
    score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True,
                                             validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(10)])
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('book', 'author')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.review
```

The form:

```
class BookReviewForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Review
        fields = ('review', 'score',)
```

I want to use the information given in the form to create a new review in which the currently logged in user is `author` and `book` is the book from the DetailView we are in, but I can't figure out how to validate and save.

I tried adding this to `BookComment` for validation:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    if form.is_valid():
        return super().form_valid(self, form)
    else:
        return super().form_invalid(self, form)
```

But then I get the following error:

`form_valid() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`

Where are these 3 arguments coming from, and how can I create the new Review correctly?

Comment: It should be `return super().form_valid(form)` without the `self`. The `self` is passed implicitly by the `super()` proxy object.

Comment: That being said, `form_valid` is only called when the form *is* valdiated.

Comment: Thanks! What do you mean by the second comment?

Comment: that this override of `form_valid` does not do anything.

Comment: So I should just delete `form_valid` and put all the  Review creation logic in `post`?

Comment: normally the creation logic is implemented in `form_valid`. It might however be better to work with a `CreateView` here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView this will implement most of the "boilerplate" logic for you.

Comment: You mean turning `BookComment` into a `CreateView`? Would the other parts of the code stay the same?